# Scraped data is not saving to csv file as it keeps returning a blank csv file.

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

Can anyone see what's wrong with this code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import csv

def races(main_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(main_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    races = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('time-location')
    races = [race.text[:5] for race in races]
    races = [race.replace(':', '') for race in races]

    driver.close()

    return races

def scrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('racecard-ajax-link')[1].click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//[@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))

    for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
        horseName = horse.find_element_by_class_name('form-link').text
        times = horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time')
        times = [time.text for time in times]
        print('{}: {}'.format(horseName, times))
    print()

    driver.close()
```

So at this next point below I am trying to save the data to df, but it returns a blank doc when opened. Should df = open('jan1.csv', 'w+') not store the scraped data into the csv file. I'm obviously missing something but can't see what.

```
def main():
    df = open('jan1.csv', 'w+')
    df.close()
    date = '1-January-2018'
    main_url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Southwell/' + date
    for race in races(main_url):
        url = main_url + '/' + race
        print(url)
        scrape(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You open the file `jan1.csv` as `df`and then you immediately close it without doing sth with it. Apart from that you don't save your scraped data into any variable which in turn means you can't save it to file.

Comment: Ah, I think I need to add df.write('variable_name') and also save the scrape to the named variable and that should do the trick?

Comment: Exactly. See also my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems broken in several places and even with fixing it I get Timeout errors.

Try these steps:

Add pandas for easy data handling:

```
import pandas as pd

def scrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('racecard-ajax-link')[1].click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//[@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))

    # add empty list to save scraped data 
    data = []

    for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
        horseName = horse.find_element_by_class_name('form-link').text
        times = horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time')
        times = [time.text for time in times]
        print('{}: {}'.format(horseName, times))
        data.append([horseName, times])
    print()

    driver.close()

    # return your data!
    return data
```

Then change this in your main function:

```
def main():

    date = '1-January-2018'
    main_url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Southwell/' + date

    tmp = []

    for race in races(main_url):
        url = main_url + '/' + race
        print(url)
        tmp.append(scrape(url))

    df = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
        df.to_csv("jan1.csv")
```

Or if you want to stick to csv only (no pandas):

```
with open("jan1.csv", "w+") as file:
    file.write(your_data_var_here)
```

Comment: @peterzurich, thanks but it's throwing an error: NameError: name 'tmp' is not defined

Comment: @BrianC See my edit – the code block with `df` in the main function wasn't properly indented.

Comment: @BrianC If it still doesn't work: Could adjust your code so it doesn`t throw the Timeout error?

Comment: Yeah I caught the indent but still throws tmp is not defined. Any suggestions on how to adjust my code?

Comment: On the Timeout error, when I run the code I originally posted, it scrapes the data fine so not sure why it's throwing you the Timeout error.

Comment: @BrianC Where exactly do you get the error? Have you tried to print the result of `scrape(url)` e.g. with `print(data)` or with `print(scrape(url))`? And are you sure that you have added `return data` to your scrape() function?